# Why jboss picking the infinispan cache not Ehcache

Tags: ehcache, jboss6.x, infinispan

I have migrated my project from glassfish2.2.1 to JBoss eap-6.0.
After migrating to Jboss, i am getting the below issue

> 17:38:45,581 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread
>   Pool -- 62) MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.persistenceunit."unbranded.ear#entityManager":
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.persistenceunit."unbranded.ear#entityManager":
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
>   entityManager] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory   at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:100)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>   [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>   [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>   [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]     at
>   org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
>
> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
>   entityManager] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory   at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:197)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$500(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:96)
>     ... 4 more
>
> Caused by: **org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: Unsupported access type
>   [nonstrict-read-write]**  at
>   **org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.EntityRegionImpl.buildAccessStrategy(EntityRegionImpl.java:33)**
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:345)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1746)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
>     ... 9 more

If you checked the logs in bold it is taking the infinispan cache, that's why it is causing the issue Unsupported access type [nonstrict-read-write], because infinispan doesn't support this one.

But is my persistence.xml i have configured the ehcache. Below is my persistence.xml

> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
>   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
>   version="1.0">    
>         org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
>         jdbc/ejb/unbranded
>           casinomodule.core.audit.AuditTrail
>
> ```
>      <!-- <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory"/> -->
>      <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup"/>
>      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
>      <property name="hibernate.query.jpaql_strict_compliance" value="false"/>
>      <property name="hibernate.session_factory_name" value="HibernateSession"/>
>      <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer" value="true"/>
>
>
>      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider"/>
>      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
>
>   </properties>    </persistence-unit> </persistence>
> ```

Don't know why jboss is taking the infinispan instead of Ehcache.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i figure out the problem.

This is causing due to old maven dependency and a property which i added in my persistence.xml file.

Below is the maven dependency:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
      </dependency>
```

Below is the new property added in my persistence.xml file.

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
```

This is happening because i am using JBoss eap-6.0. which also used hibernate as JPA provider and it is using hibernate 4.1.9.Final version. And previously in my maven i had given the dependency of hibernate as 3.4.6